# HTTP Content-Security-Policy header not working correctly for script-src in Struts

Tags: javascript, java, security, struts2, content-security-policy

I have a problem updating my version of struts struts2-core-2.5.30 project to struts2-core-6.1.1 so I began to receive an error indicating that the security policies have been violated, doing some research, I found that a header should be added

> [Report Only] Refused to load the script '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-MOz6w31eaDHGUDfV__K8LEZ1' 'strict-dynamic' http: https:". Note that 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based allowlisting is disabled. Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

and inside this error I have this description

> [Report Only] Refused to load the script `http://localhost:8080/Portal/html/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js` because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-MOz6w31eaDHGUDfV__K8LEZ1' 'strict-dynamic' http: https:". Note that 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based allowlisting is disabled. Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

> [Report Only] Refused to load the script `http://localhost:8080/Portal/html/js/jquery/jquery-ui.1.10.4.min.js` because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-MOz6w31eaDHGUDfV__K8LEZ1' 'strict-dynamic' http: https:". Note that 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based allowlisting is disabled. Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

however I have tried these headers

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">


<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
    style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline'
    'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src *
    'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src  'nonce-rAnd0m'">
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/html/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" nonce="rAnd0m123"></script>
```

with each of them I get the same error, In my previous version of Struts it did not ask me for any of this.

I have also tried to make an interceptor to add the corresponding directives, however it did not work for me either.

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.struts2.StrutsStatics;


public class SessionInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


   public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
     
    ActionContext ac = invocation.getInvocationContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ac.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);
    //HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();

    response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
    response.addHeader("Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self'; media-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; report-uri REDACTED");
    response.addHeader("X-Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self'; media-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; report-uri REDACTED");
    return invocation.invoke();
}

}
```

In the same way I have updated the jquery-1.8.3 version as suggested in the comments but it dod not worked for me either

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Struts provides support for [`Content-Security-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) since [version 6.x](https://github.com/apache/struts/commit/4d8bec5d0a56dd8fefaf3783ed57ae65139525cc).

The functionality is implemented primarily in [`CspInterceptor`](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/4d58dd1960a6fefef562ed578c42e3671c357279/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/csp/CspInterceptor.java).

This interceptor is configured by providing a convenient [default implementation](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/8c4a90f6e3b20697d3e57134a983b2c694e5fe75/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/csp/DefaultCspSettings.java) of [CspSettings](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/253d8558e55737084f56a0fab3c32ee3deee9cee/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/csp/CspSettings.java).

This interceptor is included by default in the [Struts configuration](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/struts-default.xml). As you can see in the [linked resource](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/2a85d0fbc4dcc8e59b4e48d1c8289252ade042af/core/src/main/resources/struts-default.xml#L199) and in [the documentation](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/csp-interceptor) by default is configured in report only, non enforcing mode:

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="csp">
  <param name="disabled">false</param>
  <param name="enforcingMode">false</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

I reviewed the current source code of the library and the companion documentation and it seems that providing a custom CSP configuration to `CspInterceptor` is not possible right now.

That means that in order to mitigate your error one possibility will be to disable the `CspInterceptor` and provide your own. The [Struts documentation](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/interceptors#disabling-interceptor) provides guidance about how it could be accomplished. In your case, I think it should look like similar to the following:

```xml
<action name="myAction" class="myActionClass">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
        <param name="csp.disabled">true</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</action>
```

In addition, in the [commit](https://github.com/apache/struts/commit/4d8bec5d0a56dd8fefaf3783ed57ae65139525cc) I cited at the beginning of the answer they mention the components and corresponding tags [`s:link`](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/components/Link.java) and [`s:script`](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/components/Script.java) as a possible way for fetching the required CSS and Javascript resources taking into account the default CSP settings: basically they provide the necessary mechanisms for taking into account the appropriate nonces for the linked resources, required according to the policy applied. Please, consider review for instance [this page](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/apps/showcase/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/decorators/main.jsp) in the showcase provided by Struts as example, reproduced here for convenience:

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>


<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- content removed for brevity -->

    <s:url var="jqueryJs" value='/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js' encode='false' includeParams='none'/>
    <s:script src="%{jqueryJs}"/>
    <!-- other resources... now handling inline sources --> 
    <s:script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var alerts = $('ul.alert').wrap('<div />');
            alerts.prepend('<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>');
            alerts.alert();
        });
    </s:script>


    <!-- ... -->
</head>
```

Comment: @SebastianRuiz Were you able to test any of the proposed solutions?

Comment: You are welcome @SebastianRuiz. I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful.

Comment: I have used the `<s:script>` and `<s:link>` tags, they are an elegant and very secure solution for CSP. However, I am trying to figure out how to allow my base-uri. If I can't do that I guess I will make my own interceptor.

Answer (score 4):

I was also struggling with the new Content Security Policy interceptor.  We had to temporarily disable it since Struts doesn't really provide any way to configure it yet and all of those browser console error / CSP reports are really unacceptable.

At least for me, in order to disable it across all of my actions in struts.xml I needed to reference "cspInterceptor" instead of "csp" as follows:

```
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" >
    <param name="cspInterceptor.disabled">true</param>              
</interceptor-ref>
```

Comment: For some reason they renamed it from "csp" to "cspInterceptor" but didn't update their documentation.

Comment: It looks like it was a mistake and will be fixed in a future release, but meanwhile their documentation is wrong: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-5263. Wasted a huge amount of time figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

The content of your policies and the one in the error message don't match, and while you are adding "Content-Security-Policy", the error message is for "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only". This means that there is another header present, and you are adding another. Adding another can only make the policy stricter. The report only version of Content-Security-Policy doesn't actually block anything, and must be set as a response header. You should identify where this header is set and modify it as needed.

Additionally you should replace jquery-1.8.3 with a recent version that doesn't have known vulnerabilities.

Comment: hello thank you very much friend, I tried to find something that adds that header, however I have not found it since this error has arisen when I have updated the version of struts

Comment: Could be code, web server, proxy, frameworks... If code/config is searchable you should be able to find "content-security-policy-report-only" (in some casing), "strict-dynamic" or "nonce-" as they should fairly unique strings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the [Report Only] Refused to load the script message ... and struts 6.1.2.
The solution was to disable the csp as @jccampanero pointed.
I'm using actions with anotations so I had to configure the struts convention default package in the struts.xml, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 6.0//EN"
        "https://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-6.0.dtd">
<struts>  
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">  
        <interceptors>          
            <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
                 <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" >
                    <param name="cspInterceptor.disabled">true</param>              
                </interceptor-ref>
             </interceptor-stack>
         </interceptors>
    </package> 

  <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="default"/>
</struts>
```